# python tensorflow won't install

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I've tried to install **tensorflow** (python 3.5) in many ways without succeed:

1. By typing "pip install tensorflow" and "pip install tensorflow-gpu" and 
    getting the error:

> ```
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from 
>    versions: )
>    No matching distribution found for tensorflow
> ```

2. By the command: "pip install tensorflow-1.2.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64"
   with several .whl files and got the error:

   ```
   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-
   1.2.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64 (from versions: )
   No matching distribution found for tensorflow-1.2.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-
   win_amd64
   ```
3. I've even usen conda but it did not worked out..

Can you help me install tensorflow?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On which OS you are trying to install?
try below command on conda

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.0.0
```

if received error:
 `conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
 activate tensorflow
 pip install tensorflow`

Comment: I'm using windows.
You command gave me the error:


Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python 3.6*
  - tensorflow 1.0.0* -> python 3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.

Comment: try : below command   conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
pip install tensorflow

Comment: The command gave me the error:
CondaValueError: Value error: prefix already exists: C:\hi\envs\tensorflow

Comment: can you follow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180652/condavalueerror-value-error-prefix-already-exists and accept the answer and close this as the now the error is different