# An error occured when I wanted to used conda shared virtual environment：CondaValueError: prefix already exists: E:\ano

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, conda, valueerror, virtual-environment

I want to use the virtual environment that my friend shared with me，which named '`python38_env.yml`'.
But when I entered the command below in the command window:

```
conda env create -f /TuXiangKeShe/License_Plate/python38_env.ym
```

An error occured:

```
CondaValueError: prefix already exists: E:\ano
```

How Can I solve it?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180652/condavalueerror-value-error-prefix-already-exists